# ZFS on linux mount help

Tags: debian, mount, zfs

I have a following problem with zfs and especially with zfs mount.

I have installed Debian Jessie and zfs-on-linux and I want to mount /var into zfs pool. For this reason I created zfs create -o mountpoint=/var rpool/var, zfs filesystem was created, but /var was not mounted into rpool/var because directory /var is not empty.

I did following: **zfs mount -O rpool/var** and /var was mounted into rpool/var I can see in df -h output my rpool/var , but after reboot I cant see rpool/var in df -h output (I allowed overlay mounts in zfs config), but when I rsync my /var directory with rpool/var directory and delete everything in /var directory all was OK after reboot and I was happy :), but it is a correct solution? rsync and then delete/empty source /var directory? Is there another way to do this?

Thank you so much for your answers and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the normal way to migrate a file system from one storage location to another, so yes, **what you describe was the correct thing to do.**